# Low on internal data storage - looks like the some apps use a lot!

Tags: internal-storage

So, looking at the Gmail, Twitter, and Facebook apps for example, the apps themselves only take up 3-4 MB each, but then the app data is like 10+ MB for each. Is that stored data the synced copies of my email inbox, or my twitter feed, or FB feed? And, if so, is there a way for me to limit how much of my phone's internal storage each app gets allocated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There really isn't much control you can do over limiting storage.  Most likely the data is from the apps using local SQLite databases to store information their apps use.

You can pretty much only do these things:

- Move the app to the SD card if you have Android 2.2
- Clear the data cache every now and then (but it's going to grow again)

Comment: The Move to SD card button is grayed out for apps like Twitter and Gmail. :-\

Comment: Android's restrictions on what can and can't be moved to the SD card are, well, restrictive. Annoyingly so. In addition to background service use and other "advanced" app features that prevent moving to SD, it seems that any app that comes preinstalled can't be moved, even if you upgrade it from Market.

Answer (score 3):

For limiting GMail storage, at least --

Fire up the GMail client. Click Menu > Settings > Labels
From there you can select how many days worth you want synced overall, and per label. Reducing the number could help cut down on the clutter.

Answer (score 0):

There are some games around that use over 80+ megabytes of space. Cleaning those up first should give you some breathing space.

Comment: The largest applications on my phone right now are Gmail and Twitter, both 18+ MB.